# Computing histogram of particular column variable in R

Tags: r, histogram

So I'm interested in making a histogram of values just for the "NV" variable (the column contains either "NV" or "VV".) How can I extract just these particular values?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As you don't provide a reproducible example:

dummy data

```
df <- data.frame(id=c(rep("NV",15),rep("VV",15)),value=sample(x = 1:100,size = 30,replace = TRUE))
```

create histogram by subsetting the needed values

```
hist(df[df$id=="NV",]$value)
```

or

```
hist(df[df$id=="NV",2])
```